# how to add keys in this project

Tags: reactjs, react-native

im using react o nexpo xde and when i run the project i get a warning because my list doesnt hae keys, i want to know where and how to assing them, this is my code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View,AppRegistry,Image,ActivityIndicator, FlatList,Navigator,TouchableHighlight, } from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

  class Lista extends Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
      title: 'Lista',
    }
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        data:[]
      };

    }
    load = async ()=>{
      try{
        let resp = await fetch('https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&category=business&apiKey=fd829ddc49214efb935920463668608d')
        let json = await resp.json()
        this.setState({data:json.articles})
      } catch (err) { console.log(err) }
    }

    componentDidMount(){this.load()}
    render() {
      return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1}}>
          <View style={{ flex:1,backgroundColor:'gray'}}>
            <FlatList
              data={this.state.data}
              renderItem={({item}) => (
                <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Details', {item})}>
                  <View style={{ height:100,margin:15,backgroundColor:'skyblue', padding: 10, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                    {item.urlToImage !== null &&
                      <Image source={{uri:item.urlToImage}} style={{width: 90, height: 80 }}/>
                    }
                    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                      <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center',fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 18, color: 'white', flex:1, margin:10}}>{item.title}</Text>
                      <Text style={{ textAlign: 'right',fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 11, color: 'white'}}>{item.publishedAt}</Text>
                    </View>
                  </View>
                </TouchableHighlight>
              )}
            />
          </View>
        </View>
      );
    }
  }
  class DetailsScreen extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
      const { item } = navigation.state;
      return {
        title: item ? item.date : 'Details Screen',
      }
    };

    render() {
      return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
          <Image source={{uri:this.props.navigation.state.params.item.urlToImage}} style={{width: 90, height: 80 }}/>
          <Text>{this.props.navigation.state.params.item.title}</Text>
          <Text>{this.props.navigation.state.params.item.publishedAt}</Text>
        </View>
      );
    }
  }

  const RootStack = StackNavigator(
    {
      Lista: {
        screen: Lista,
      },
      Details: {
        screen: DetailsScreen,
      },
    },
    {
      initialRouteName: 'Lista',
    }
  );
  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
      backgroundColor: '#fff',
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
    },
  });

  export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return <RootStack />;
    }
  }
```

i know it has to be something like, key={i} bu i hae tried in some ways and it doesnt work, im just learning react by myself so im a little confused here
ty so much

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys

Comment: `my list doesnt hae keys`: which is the list that raises this error? What have you tried to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you need to set up key to each child of `<FlatList />` component. By react native docs recomended to use [keyExtractor](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html) method defined in your component.

```
 keyExtractor = (item, index) => index

 render() {

 return (
  <View style={{ flex: 1}}>
    <View style={{ flex:1,backgroundColor:'gray'}}>
     <FlatList
      data={this.state.data}
      keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
      renderItem={({item}) => (

      <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Details', {item})}>
    <View style={{ height:100,margin:15,backgroundColor:'skyblue', padding: 10, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
      {item.urlToImage !== null &&
        <Image source={{uri:item.urlToImage}} style={{width: 90, height: 80 }}/>
      }
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <Text style= {{ textAlign: 'center',fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 18, color: 'white', flex:1, margin:10}}>{item.title}</Text>
        <Text style= {{ textAlign: 'right',fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 11, color: 'white'}}>{item.publishedAt}</Text>
       </View>
      </View>
     </TouchableHighlight>
      )}
    />
    </View>
  </View>

    );
 }
```

I set just index of element as key, but you can set as you wont, but make sure it is unique. But using indexes is bad practice, it is not safe.

Comment: Using the `index` as a `key` is not safe. Adding, removing or reordering items will lead to incorrect behaviour. You shoud only do this for static data that never changes.

Comment: @trixn, I know, i just set index as example to clearify my answer. I edit it to write your recommend, thanks.